# Should I include module.exports above or below constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, codacy

I'm using [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/) for my project and i'm getting a warning saying that I shouldn't use variables which I declare later, which is quite logical. However, this should work fine for constructors.

This is my main file structure:

```
/* Export */
module.exports = myObject; // this line

/* Import */
var otherObject = require('./otherObject');

function myObject(input) {
}

myObject.prototype = {
}
```

Could any problems occur by exporting before the object constructor declaration? Should I move the export line below the constructor like?

Comment: It works fine for *function declarations*, not constructors. Anyway, it’s more or less a matter of style; you can put it wherever you like best. `if (module)` doesn’t make much sense, though.

Comment: @Ryan thanks for the tip on `if (module)`, I used it because I saw it in other projects, but it's not necessary indeed.

Comment: Have a look at *hoisting*. All your code is behind your function declaration...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will put **the correct function** in `module.exports` because of function hoisting:

```
module.exports = myObject;
function myObject(input) {
}
```

This will put **`undefined`** in `module.exports` (with no error) because of variable hoisting:

```
module.exports = myObject;
var myObject = function (input) {
};
```

This will raise `ReferenceError: myObject is not defined` **exception** because of the `let` scoping rules:

```
module.exports = myObject;
let myObject = function (input) {
};
```

and so will this becasue of `const` scoping:

```
module.exports = myObject;
const myObject = function (input) {
};
```

On the other hand, all of those will work the same and as expected if you put `module.exports = myObject;` at the end - which you'll have to do anyway if you follow e.g. the Airbnb coding style:

- http://airbnb.io/javascript/

or if you use some linter rules, e.g. this ESLint rule:

- http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define

> **Disallow Early Use (no-use-before-define)**
>
> In JavaScript, prior to ES6, variable and function declarations are hoisted to the top of a scope, so it’s possible to use identifiers before their formal declarations in code. This can be confusing and some believe it is best to always declare variables and functions before using them.
>
> In ES6, block-level bindings (let and const) introduce a “temporal dead zone” where a ReferenceError will be thrown with any attempt to access the variable before its declaration.